# Data sets with floating points

Tags: java

My main program will create a DataSet object, read in values and call the addValue instance method until it encounters a negative value. Then it will call the getAverage and getStandardDeviation methods and print out the return results. the average is 3.28
the Standard Deviation is 1.972815247
this is my code. I'm basically stuck right now.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DataSet {

    private double value;
    private double count;
    private double sum;
    private double sumofSquares;


    public void addValue(double value) {
        while (value >= 0) {
            count++;
            sum += value;
            sumofSquares += (value * value);

        }

    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return sum / count;

    }

    public double getStandardDeviation() {
        return Math.sqrt(((count * sumofSquares) - (sum * sum)) / (count * (count - 1)));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Value");
    double value = sc.nextDouble();
    DataSet j1 = new DataSet();
    j1.addValue(value);
    System.out.println("The average of the value " + j1.getAverage());
    System.out.println("The Standard Deviation of the value" + j1.getStandardDeviation());

    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot wrong with this code. Firstly, your input code is not inside of a while loop, so you are not going to intake any new values. Secondly, your addValue function invokes an infinite loop upon entering a positive value, because the while loop will continue to run and add to your DataSet members.

I've refactored your code to make more sense, ask if you have any questions on any specific areas.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DataSet {

private double value;
private double count;
private double sum;
private double sumofSquares;


public int addValue(double value) {
    if(value >= 0) {
        count++;
        sum += value;
        sumofSquares += (value * value);
        return 0;
    }else{
        System.out.println("The average of the value " + this.getAverage());
        System.out.println("The Standard Deviation of the value " + this.getStandardDeviation());
        return -1;
    }
}

public double getAverage() {
    return sum / count;

}

public double getStandardDeviation() {
    return Math.sqrt(((count * sumofSquares) - (sum * sum)) / (count * (count - 1)));

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Values");

    double value = 0;
    DataSet j1 = new DataSet();

    while(true){
        value = sc.nextDouble(); 

        if(j1.addValue(value) == 0){
            //continue
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

}